Find queries that has Sch-S Lock on a resource in Azure SQL/ SQL Server for more than 5 minutes
Following query gives different types of locks. I observed that some queries are keeping Sch-S lock on a resource long time.
I referred https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/328283/why-does-a-select-query-sch-s-get-blocked-due-to-an-existing-sch-s-lock-held-b to get some idea about these locks.
SELECT dm_tran_locks.request_session_id,
       dm_tran_locks.resource_database_id,
       DB_NAME(dm_tran_locks.resource_database_id) AS dbname,
       CASE
           WHEN resource_type = 'OBJECT'
               THEN OBJECT_NAME(dm_tran_locks.resource_associated_entity_id)
           ELSE OBJECT_NAME(partitions.OBJECT_ID)
       END AS ObjectName,
       dm_tran_locks.resource_type,
       dm_tran_locks.resource_description,
       dm_tran_locks.resource_associated_entity_id,
       dm_tran_locks.request_mode,
       dm_tran_locks.request_status
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks
LEFT JOIN sys.partitions ON partitions.hobt_id = dm_tran_locks.resource_associated_entity_id
LEFT JOIN sys.indexes ON indexes.OBJECT_ID = partitions.OBJECT_ID AND indexes.index_id = partitions.index_id
WHERE resource_associated_entity_id > 0
  AND resource_database_id = DB_ID()
ORDER BY request_session_id, resource_associated_entity_id 

Questions

How do I identify associated queries that caused this lock for more than 5 minutes?
What is the best way to log such queries (caused this lock for more than 5 minutes)


Can you show us the actual returned data that you see? The more context we have, the better.

The query you need may look like the one below:
SELECT
    blockerSession = conn.session_id
    ,BlockedSession = conn2.session_id
    ,Waiting_Time_ms = req.wait_time
    ,Waiting_Time_secs = CAST((req.wait_time / 1000.) AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
    ,Waiting_Time_mins = CAST((req.wait_time / 1000. / 60.) AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
    ,BlockerQuery = t.text
    ,BlockedQuery = t2.text
    ,req.wait_type
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS req
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS conn ON req.blocking_session_id = conn.session_id
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS conn2 ON req.session_id = conn2.session_id
INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_locks AS tr ON tr.request_session_id = conn.session_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(conn.most_recent_sql_handle) AS t
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(conn2.most_recent_sql_handle) AS t2
WHERE tr.request_mode = 'Sch-S'
      AND CAST((req.wait_time / 1000. / 60.) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) > 5;

You may want to schedule its execution every X minutes using Azure Automation and log the results into a table.
